# Remove delay() on click event

Tags: jquery, delay

I have a panel who slide automatically after 13 seconds. I made this with jquery.delay().
The problem appears if I want to manually slide the panel with a click event. It appears that the click event is waiting the end of the delay to effect..

What can I use in place of delay()?

My code :

The delay part:

```
$('#menu').delay(13000).hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400, function () {
            if ($('#menu').is(':hidden')) {
                $('#trigger').removeClass("triggerdroiteExtended");
                $('#trigger').addClass("triggerdroiteCollapsed");
                $.cookie('rightfold', 'collapsed', { path: '/' });
            }
        });
```

The Click event part:

```
  $('#triggerdroite').click(function () { foo
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a place you're probably better off using [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout) and [`clearTimeout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-cleartimeout). From the [`delay` docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited — **it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay** — `.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

*(My emphasis.)*

So in this case:

```
(function() {
    var slideTimer = 0;
    slideTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#menu').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 400, function () {
                if ($('#menu').is(':hidden')) {
                    $('#trigger').removeClass("triggerdroiteExtended");
                    $('#trigger').addClass("triggerdroiteCollapsed");
                    $.cookie('rightfold', 'collapsed', { path: '/' });
                }
            });
    }, 13000);
    $('#triggerdroite').click(function() {
        if (slideTimer) {
            clearTimeout(slideTimer);
            slideTimer = 0;
        }

        // ...
    });
})();
```

(The outer anonymous function is just a placeholder, I assume your code is already inside some function to prevent creating globals.)

Note I'm using `0` as a "no timer running" value. `0` is not a valid return value from `setTimeout`, so it's a useful flag.

Of course, rather than storing this in a variable as I have above, you could always store it on the `#menu` element itself using [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data).

Comment: thnks it's working fine but you invert parameters of SetTimout() it is the function first and after the delay.

Comment: @bAN: OMG, fixed. (Earlier I called `clearTimeout` `cancelTimeout` as well, it's been a very long day.) Glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already 8 years old (at the time this answer is written) but I thought I would suggest a much easier approach, which I even see as the intended way to something like this. I don't know if this function was already available at the time the accepted answer was written, so I write this answer just in case.

You can use the method [`clearQueue()`](https://api.jquery.com/clearqueue/) to clear up every function that is still about to be called (functions like `delay`, `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, and much more...

It even does have the option to pass a parameter to say which functions should be removed from the queue.

I used this exact approach in one of my projects. The good thing is:

- You don't have to worry about global constants
- You can keep writing the necessary code with jQuery functions.

**Example from my project:**

```
function add_notifications(type, ...messages)
{
    var div_notification =
        $('<div class="notification ' + type + '"></div>');

    // doing stuff not important to visualize use of clearQueue() ...

    div_notification.on('click', function() {
        $(this).clearQueue();
        $(this).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        })
    });

    div_notification.hide().fadeIn(500, function() {
        $(this).delay(10000).fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    div_notification.appendTo('div#notifications');
}
```